# Make document getElementById as Int

Tags: javascript, string, int

I have this code that add numbers and prints it in input text for readonly

```
document.getElementById('total') += parseInt(tot);
```

but it JUST adds numbers as sting , for example when add 8 and 10 that would be 18 but it prints them as 810 , why ?

Comment: you are using getElementById wrong, it returns an element node. And cannot be set, you should be getting left hand side assignment error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('total');
elem.value = +elem.value + parseInt(tot);
```

The `+` sign force the type to number.

Comment: Why the down vote? It works perfectly (if the string is a valid number of course), I've just tried `+'123' + 12` in the console just to be sure and it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parseInt()` function to both of them:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(tot)+parteInt(document.getElementById('total').value);
```

Comment: that's give me : Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: added value to inject new value

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the value from string to integer like this

```
var x = document.getElementById('total');    
x.value = parseInt(x.value) + parseInt(tot);
```

Or use `parseFloat()` if you have decimal numbers.